# Lumen8 Delete Method not working Other Get put and Other are Working

Tags: laravel, lumen

```php
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('users', ['as' => 'users.store', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@store']);
    $router->get('users', ['as' => 'users.index', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@index']);
    $router->get('users/{user}', ['as' => 'users.show', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@show']);
    $router->put('users/{user}', ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@update']);
    $router->delete('users/{user}', ['as' => 'users.destroy', 'uses' => 'User\UserController@delete']);
});
```

`GET`, `POST` and `PUT` are working but `DELETE` method is getting `404` error.

[image]

Comment: You want to blind me with that `light theme`... Do you know that you can use [`apiResource`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#api-resource-routes) so you have 1 declaration instead of all those 5 routes ? EDIT: you are using lumen, forget it then...

Comment: Are you sure `{{base_url}}` is correct ? Do you know if user id `1002` exists on database ?

Comment: Yes {{base_url}} is enviromaent varibale in post that is locahost:8000 Then I have the reacord in Db {{base_url}}/api/users/1002 Here I can view the record

Comment: You will have to share the `UserController`'s `delete` method, there is something wrong there.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes your correct smell mistake function name is deleted